# Unable to create layer for RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have a recyclerview that load images. On Android Pie, I faced with this issue:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for RecyclerView, size 768x4992 max size 8192 color type 4 has context 1
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

I don't have any image transition or animation.
What is that means and what should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: hi, @Masoud Mokhtari can you post some code plz!

Comment: your image resolution is high so its allocated memory is not sufficient use Glide or picasso to load images and grant large heap in Android Manifest 
see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Try to input this code in your parent in XML File **android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false"**

To ignore all overlaps sizes within your xml.